# Data base Android stuck

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got a little problem with my data base. I've followed with an example on the website to create everything necessary to work with data base. Unfortunately it does not want to work. I've got error message with text: Table gifs has no column named rating, while trying to insert object to that table. I understand this message but I really don't get why if everything should work fine. It's simple data base wchich should for now add objects. Why it can not find that column if it is created when the data base is created?

Here is a code from MAINACTIVITY:

```
 dataBaseManager.insertGifToDataBase(tmpGif);
```

where tmpGif has fields: Name, Date, rating and url. Except rating the rest are Strings.

Here is my SQLiteHelper and Class wchich manages the data base:

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "gifs";
  public static final String NAME = "name";
  public static final String RATING = "rating";
  public static final String DATE = "date";
  public static final String URL = "url";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gifs.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + "text" + "," + RATING + "int" + "," + URL + "text" + "," + DATE + "text" + ");";

public SqliteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    //Log.i("DATA BASE", getDatabaseName());
  }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

     database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(database);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the spaces between column name and datatype for the correct structure in create table query:

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + "text" + "," + RATING + "int" + "," + URL + "text" + "," + DATE + "text" + ");";
```

should be:

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + " text" + "," + RATING + " int" + "," + URL + " text" + "," + DATE + " text" + ");";
```

So the table is not created properly and column cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you for this annotation. It's helped

Answer (score 1):

You need spaces between column names and their types here:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + " text" + "," + RATING + " int" + "," + URL + " text" + "," + DATE + " text" + ");";
```

so e.g. the rating is `rating int` and not `ratingint`.

After updating the SQL, uninstall your app so that old database file gets removed.

Comment: Thank You for quick answer. Yeah now it works after your steps. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is a need to slight change for yours `DATABASE_CREATE`

please do it as follows

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + NAME + " text" + "," + RATING + " int" + "," + URL + " text" + "," + DATE + " text" + ");";
```